# Решение задачи в книге Кормена "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"

Tags: математика

Делаю задания в книге Кормена "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ". Не могу понять один момент в такой вот задаче на странице 86, подпункт е:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответах для А=lg(n!) и B=lg(n^n) в случае о(о малое) написано, что - нет. Хотя у меня получается ответ - да. Я пользуюсь формулой из книги, чтобы доказать, что lg(n!)=o(lg(n^n)):

0 <= lg(n!) < c * lg(n^n).

Т.к. lg(n!) <= lg(n^n) при n > 1. То при любой c: lg(n!) <= c * lg(n^n). Получается, что lg(n!)=o(lg(n^n)).
Но я смотрел ответы в разных источниках, и там написано что это не так.
Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём я не прав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lg(n!) = ∑<sub>1≤i≤n</sub>lg(i) ≥* <sub>(оставляем только старшую половину суммы)</sub>

*≥ ∑<sub>n/2≤i≤n</sub>lg(i) ≥* <sub>(оценка элементов снизу)</sub>

*≥ ∑<sub>n/2≤i≤n</sub>lg(n/2) =* <sub>(сворачиваем сумму)</sub>

*= (n/2)lg(n/2) =* <sub>(выделяем из суммы *nlg(n)*)</sub>

*= (n/2)(lg(n) - lg(2)) = (n/2)(lg(n)(1 - lg(2)/lg(n))) = ((1 - lg(2)/lg(n))/2) n·lg(n) ≥*

<sub>(вводим константу *C = (1 - lg(2)/lg(n<sub>0</sub>))/2*)</sub>

*≥ C·n·lg(n)*

Последнее неравенство верно начиная с любого *n<sub>0</sub> > 2*.

То что *lg(n!) ≤ lg(n<sup>n</sup>)* (логарифм факториала растёт не быстрее логарифма степени) вы уже знаете. Выше доказана обратная оценка - логарифм степени растёт не быстрее логарифма факториала.

Правильный ответ - *θ*.

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая [формула Стирлинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда, думаю, все сразу же становится очевидным :)

Если рассмотреть отношение логарифмов *n!* и *n<sup>n</sup>*, то предел такого отношения равен  1.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Видимо я вообще не туда копал. А почему предел равен 1? Если я правильно, понимаю, чем больше n, тем lg(n!)/lg(n^n) меньше. И предел равен 0.

Comment: lg(n!) ~ (n + 1/2)lg(n) - n lg(e) +const. Отношение к n lg(n) стремится к 1.